Switching out Dolphin file manager for Thunar , now folders open in KATE from within other programs
Pretty much the whole thing is in the title but in a nutshell: If I'm in a program like qBittorrent & I want to 'open destination folder' of a given file, the result is Kate opens instead of Thunar.
One note- This is an otherwise plain-vanilla install of Ubuntu Studio v23.10 w/ one notable exception: I uninstall the default File Manager; Dolphin for Thunar, which I prefer.
